# Troubles with nested queries

Tags: mysql

I have this query which works perfectly:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE SacCode IN
(
    SELECT SacCode
    FROM SacCode
    WHERE ResellerCorporateID = 392
    ORDER BY SacCode
)
AND CustomerID IN
(
    SELECT CxID
    FROM CustAppointments
    WHERE AppRoomID IN
    (
        SELECT AppRoomID
        FROM ClinicRooms
        WHERE ClinID IN
        (
            SELECT ClinID
            FROM AppClinics
            WHERE ClinDate >='20090101'
            AND ClinDate <='20091119'
        )
    )
)
```

However, I need to see the value of ClinDate (inside the last nested query)...

How do I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this not possible with JOINS? You could get all the data you needed then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rewrite the query using joins.  Then, you can access any data from any of the joined tables.

For example, you could rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT c.*, ac.ClinDate
FROM Customer c
  JOIN SacCode sc ON sc.SacCode = c.SacCode
  JOIN CustAppointments ca ON ca.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
  JOIN ClinicRooms cr ON cr.AppRoomID = ca.AppRoomID
  JOIN AppClinic ac ON ac.ClinID = cr.ClinID
WHERE ac.ClinDate >='20090101'
  AND ac.ClinDate <='20091119'
  AND sc.ResellerCorporateID = 392
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I'd use derived table in the FROM statement rather than 3 deep nested query, will allow you to access values and will look a LOT better.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to copy the subselects to the FROM clause or rewrite the query using JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

it should look something like this:

```
SELECT c.*, a.ClinDate

FROM Customer c

inner join CustAppointments ca
inner join ClinicRooms cr
inner join AppClinics a

where c.SacCode IN
(
    SELECT SacCode
    FROM SacCode
    WHERE ResellerCorporateID = 392
    ORDER BY SacCode
)

and c.CustomerID = ca.CxID
and ca.AppRoomID = cr.AppRoomID
and cr.ClinID = a.ClinID

and a.ClinDate >='20090101' 
and a.ClinDate <='20091119'
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, but I can get it to work...

Where does s.SacCode come from?

Comment: that should be c.SacCode as you are selecting from the inline query i.e. there is not join to SacCode

Comment: ...although you could do (see answer from Jim)